# Convert epoch String to Java date

Tags: java, parsing, date, datetime, epoch

I am getting an epoch String from my DB which looks something like this : 1391328000000

I am having a hard time trying to convert it to Java Date.

I tried the following  :

```
private String buildDate(String dateString){
        System.out.println("dateString " + dateString);

        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
        String formatted = format.format(Integer.parseInt(dateString));

        return formatted;
    }
```

Comment: Well what date is that meant to represent? And do you really have to get it as a string rather than as a number? (I suspect it's actually milliseconds since the unix epoch.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're overthinking about the `DateFormat`. If I want to simply obtain a `Date` instance, what I would try is the following:

```
Date d = new Date(Long.parseLong(dateString));
```

Comment: Please note the epoch string the asker used as an example is in Milliseconds. If you are workign with epoch in seconds, you should: new Date(Long.parseLong(dateString) * 1000)

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn it into a `java.util.Date` object in order for `SimpleDateFormat` to handle it. Also, a value like what you quoted needs to be parsed as a `long`, as it is too large for an `int`.

That is, change the line where you set `formatted` to be:

```
String formatted = format.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(dateString)));
```

As an aside, if the project you're working on can handle an extra external dependency, switch date/time handling over to the [joda library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). The stuff in `java.util` (that is, `Date` and `Calendar`) rapidly becomes painful and error-prone to work with.

Comment: You don't actually have to make a Date with SimpleDateFormat.  The implementation of `java.text.Format#format(Object obj)` is friendly enough to convert Number to Date for you.